# requiring d3 plugin with browserify

Tags: d3.js, npm, browserify

I am bringing sanity to a single page app with browserify.  However, I am getting confused with bringing in d3 plugins.  I have installed d3 and the lasso plugin thusly:

```
 npm install d3
 npm install d3-lasso
```

Then in my app I do

```
d3 = require('d3');
require('d3-lasso');
```

But then in my subsequent module:

```
function myModule() {
  var lasso = d3.lasso();
}
```

Produces this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: d3.lasso is not a function
```

I then tried:

```
d3 = require('d3');
d3.lasso = require('d3-lasso');
```

But that had the same outcome.

What is the proper way to do this?

**EDIT:**

The following idiom works:

```
d3 = require('d3');
d3.lasso=require('d3-lasso').lasso;
```

But seems a bit unwieldy.  Is there a Better(tm) way to do this (and by better I mean 'more common' or 'more generalizable' or 'more consistent with how it is done by people who do this for a living')?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your interim solution; works for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you should want to use ES6 import, the syntax that worked for me was

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { lasso } from 'd3-lasso';
d3.lasso = lasso;
```